# How is Hazelcast distributed cache faster than a call to the DB?

Tags: caching, hazelcast, distributed-caching

Lets say there I have 2 servers that are using Hazelcasts distributed cache. If on server #1, I store 2 items in a map in that distributed cache. One of those items will be saved in the local back up, and the other will be stored in the backup of the other servers Hazelcast instance(Please correct me if that is incorrect).

My question is, if I try to retrieve the second item from the cache(stored in the backup on server #2), a TCP call will be made to retrieve that data. How is this faster than just calling the DB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all let me correct how data is stored on Hazelcast.

Hazelcast uses a distribution algorithm based on consistent hashing, meaning the hashing algorithm returns the same output for the same input all the time. This distribution is not 100% equal distribution but for high number of elements pretty good and cost effective. That said it doesn't mean you'll have one element on each node in the worst case.

By default Hazelcast also keeps on backup, that means each node will have both elements (in a 2 node setup), either owned data or as a backup for failure case. You can make backups readable (read-from-backup=true), however that introduces a slight chance to read staled data (time between owner is updated but backup is not yet).

In addition data in Hazelcast, again by default, is stored in serialized form, means binary streamable representation.

Ok so how can all this be faster than a TCP connection to your database?

The answer is twofold:

1. Hazelcast is a key-value store. Therefore it is optimized for requesting data by key and answering with the value as quickly as possible.
2. Data is already serialized, therefore the byte stream is just "smashed" into the socket without any real further work to be done.

Your database on the other hand has to really query data from a table. The internal data structures to hold the information is optimized for complex queries but not to access on a key base. But, and this is important, current database implementation optimize internally (in RAM) for fast access too. So the effect will only happen for databases that serve under high load. Caches (local or distributed) are designed to speed up slow operations, resulting in: if your database is blazingly fast you won't see a benefit.

Anyways designing a system you expect to grow exponentially you should consider caching right from the start. A comprehensive introduction into caching and the behind ideas is available in a caching whitepaper and article I wrote some time ago: https://dzone.com/articles/caching-why-you-should-care

I hope this answers your question :-)

Comment: I'm not sure about point 2. If the data needs to be requested from another node, serialization is required, see here: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/serialization/serialization.htm

Comment: Apart form the fact that the original answer is from 2016, I don't think the default in-memory format has ever changed (meaning, data being serialized are stored in serialized form by default on the nodes). For more information (e.g. on map) see here: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/map#setting-in-memory-format